# Run-time 1004 error when comparing pivot item values

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I am currently working on a set of code to set a pivot table filter to a certain date range. In the code below the date range is from 12/7/2015 to 12/22/2015. In the data only dates 12/7,8,11,18 exist. The code will properly flag those items in the filer, omitting and dates before 12/7 as intended, but somehow it pulls in a 12/21/2015 date and then give me the run time error at the Bolded code row. There is no 12/21/2015 in my data at all. It is also saying that pi.visible should be false and I think that's where the error is happening because there is no 12/21/2015 for it to flag as visible or not. Any advice?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem
Dim dCurrentDate As Date, dPastDate As Date

dCurrentDate = Date
dPastDate = Date - 15

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set pt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Date")

With pf
   .ClearAllFilters
   For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
   If pi.Value = "(blank)" Then
   Else
        If pi.Value <= dCurrentDate And pi.Value >= dPastDate Then
             **pi.Visible = True**
        Else
             pi.Visible = False
        End If
    End If
   Next
End With
```

Comment: `PivotTableOptions > Data` tab. Make sure that `Retain items deleted from the data source > Number of items to retain per field:` is set to **None**. Otherwise the Cache will keep old values from the past that may have been there stored and will check them in your values, even though you do not see them in your data.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Thank you very much. This resoled the error I was having.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't need any particular dates to be there, it checks a range. I didn't get an error but it can be simplified, there is no need to check for blank.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem
Dim dCurrentDate As Date, dPastDate As Date

    dCurrentDate = Date
    dPastDate = Date - 15

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Date")

    With pf
       .ClearAllFilters
       For Each pi In pf.PivotItems

            pi.Visible = Trim(pi.Value) <= dCurrentDate And Trim(pi.Value) >= dPastDate
       Next
    End With
```

Comment: with all due to respect, this doesn't really offer an answer to the user's question at all, it just refactors his code to make it more simple / readable.